# Passing arguments via env variables through Dockerfile and Kubernetes deployment

Tags: docker, kubernetes, gitlab-ci

Hello I have a problem with manually running deployment.
I use GitlabCI, dockerfile and kubernetes.

```
FROM python:3.8

RUN mkdir /app

COPY . /app/

WORKDIR /app

RUN pip install -r requirements.txt

CMD ["python", "main.py", "${flag1}", "${ARG1}", "${flag2}, "${ARG2}"]
```

i need to run my app with command like this "python3 main.py -g argument1 -c argument2", and every run I need using other arguments. Im using this:
[image: using this]

Then my pipeline run bash script who check if variable "${ARG1}" is empty, if is empty, then unset "${FLAG1}". The next step is deploy to kubernetes using standard deployment using gitlabCI.

My idea Is bad because those environment variables aren't passing to Dockerfile. Anybody have some idea? Can't use Dockers build-args because they are don't support "CMD" step.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are using the array-syntax for the command (CMD), therefore there is no shell that could expand the variables, but the data is directly used for the `exec` system call.

If you want the variables to be expaned, use

```
CMD python main.py ${flag1} ${ARG1} ${flag2} ${ARG2}
```

or replace the command completely in kubernetes pod/replica/deployment definition, optionally with variables replaced.

Additional note: The CMD is executed at runtime of the container, not at build time.

Comment: so should i use 
CMD ["/bin/bash", "-c", "python", "main.py" "${ARG1}" etc.]?
Or some other solution?

Comment: You could do that, or just use the shell/string syntax for the CMD which is effectively the same (using /bin/sh instead of /bin/bash)

Comment: I don't understant what do you mean in "shell/string syntax for the CMD". Could you give me some example?

Comment: I created simple dockerfile with 
CMD ["/bin/bash", "-c", "echo", "${LSCOLORS}"]
LSCOLORS is in my env variables, and It does not working. that variable did not change to anything.

Comment: See the example in my answer, it does not use the array syntax, but is just a string. These variants are explained in the docker reference: https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/builder/#cmd

Comment: Ok i understand but it's working when i do this:
CMD export CATALINA_HOME=/opt/catalina && echo $CATALINA_HOME 

but not when I do this:

CMD ./set-env-vars.sh && echo $CATALINA_HOME

Comment: Even when:
source ./script.sh with
export CATALINA_HOME=/path/to
my vars in dockerfile stay the same:
CMD $CATALINA_HOME

but, when in shell I type "echo $CATALINA_HOME", then output is "path/to".

Comment: I did it using sed
reploace CATALINA_HOME from CMD into $CATALINA_HOME from env vars